# Perl format() issue - Empty lines between paragraphs get stripped and cannot be displayed

Tags: perl

I'm using Perl's [`format`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#format) and [`write`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#write-FILEHANDLE) functions to output some text.

The requirements are below:

1. Print an article (length unknown) using Perl `format`.
2. Maximum 80 characters per line.
3. Last word should be wrapped to the next line if there is not enough space.
4. Empty lines between paragraphs need to be retained.

The problem I'm having now is any blank lines between paragraphs cannot be displayed. I checked, and this seems to be caused by the use of "`~~`".

The format is defined as below.

```
format FULL_TEXT =
Full Story:
^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<~~
$storyBody
.
```

Is there a way to print this empty line between paragraphs while still meeting other requirements?

For example, below is what I expect. However, as I said before, the empty line between the two paragraphs is stripped and cannot be displayed.

**COLLINGWOOD unfurled its 2010 premiership flag at the MCG last night and marked
the occasion as protocol demanded, by lowering the colours of its
longeststanding rival, Carlton in a contest that was epic in style, if not
consequence.**

**The crowd was 88,181, a record for home-and-away contests between these clubs. An old feeling stirring in the AFL.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to split the text into paragraphs and write each paragraph at a time.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
# slurp text
my $text = do { local $/; <> };
# split into paragraphs
my @paragraphs = split /\n+/, $text;
# define format, including newline at the end
format STDOUT =
  ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$_
  ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ~~
$_

.
# write text to format
write for @paragraphs;
```

Call it like this:

```
perl /tmp/fmt.pl < /tmp/article.txt
```

If you want to or have to save memory because your articles are so big, you can combine the first two steps:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
# slurp text into paragraphs
my @paragraphs = split /\n+/, do { local $/; <> };
# define format, including newline at the end
format STDOUT =
  ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$_
  ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ~~
$_

.
write for @paragraphs; # write text to format
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your help. Although I cannot directly use your solution which is because I simplified the Format definition and the complexity of the text in my question, your idea of outputting paragraphs one by one does inspired me. As you suggested, I split the text into paragraphs and output them individually. Now I can insert an empty line between paragraphs. Problem solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
use 5;
use strictures;
use Perl6::Form;

my $storyBody = 'COLLINGWOOD unfurled its 2010 premiership flag at the MCG last night and marked the occasion as protocol demanded, by lowering the colours of its longeststanding rival, Carlton in a contest that was epic in style, if not consequence.

The crowd was 88,181, a record for home-and-away contests between these clubs. An old feeling stirring in the AFL.';

my $form = form
'Full Story:',
'{[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[}',
map {s/\n/\r\r/; $_} $storyBody;

print $form;
```

---

Output:

```
Full Story:
COLLINGWOOD unfurled its 2010 premiership flag at the MCG last night and marked
the occasion as protocol demanded, by lowering the colours of its longeststanding
rival, Carlton in a contest that was epic in style, if not consequence.

The crowd was 88,181, a record for home-and-away contests between these clubs. An
old feeling stirring in the AFL.
```

---

[Semantics of `\r` in form(?:at)?s](http://p3rl.org/Perl6::Form#Tabular_layout)

Comment: Hi daxim, Thanks for your help. The output is exactly what I'm expecting. However as this is an assignment and I must use Perl Format to do the output and no other modules can be used. Any more suggestions? Thank you.